# How do I write a vim function that calls VimGrep?

Tags: vim, vimgrep

I want to write a function myFunc such that:

```
myFunc /function foo/
```

becomes

```
:vimgrep /function foo/ **/*.cpp **/*.hpp
```

and

```
myFunc /class bar: public/
```

becomes

```
vimgrep /class bar: public/ **/*.cpp **/*.hpp
```

how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing my nose to vimgrep. That sounds very useful. Loving vim, you learn something new even after 10+ years of usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:command -nargs=1 MyFunc vimgrep <args> **/*.cpp **/*.hpp

:MyFunc /Hello world/
```

Comment: Why is this -nargs=1 and not -nargs=+ ?

Comment: Because you need only one argument and it is a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout a plugin I wrote called [EasyGrep](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2438). It has builtin support for this when you use tracked mode. What you can do is place your cursor over a word (or visually select some text) and type <leader>vv and it will search all of *.cpp *.hpp *.cxx *.hxx *.cc *.c *.h for the pattern. Once you get used to typing <leader>vv it is significantly faster than typing :Command /Pattern/.